# Keep hearing usb disconnect and reconnect sounds

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb, audio

I seem to be having a problem, for a few weeks I have been hearing the random sound of connecting and disconnecting of a USB device. nothing is shown in my tool bar and in device manager I can not see anything at all. I have no power saving options, I did a system restore which didn't fix the problem. When the sound is made my mouse and keyboard and anything else that is USB connected works fine. I have disabled my wireless card on my PC as I don't use it and I still now and then hear the wonderful sound of something being disconnected. Now I have no idea what so ever on what it could be.

So I am asking here if anyone has had this problem and what they did to resolve it, or if anyone can give me a hand on removing this terrible plague :( Also my computer is running Windows 7

P.S. At the moment I am watching a video on twitch and it is playing the sound alot...

Comment: Maybe [this](http://superuser.com/questions/125377/windows-keeps-making-these-random-device-connect-and-device-disconnect-sound) is your issue too. Or [this](http://superuser.com/questions/505739/windows-8-constantly-plays-the-device-connect-sound)?

Comment: yea something like that

Comment: There's someone with the same problem,
here's the link:

http://superuser.com/questions/125377/windows-keeps-making-these-random-device-connect-and-device-disconnect-sound

Answer (score 1):

Here's what eventually solved my problem.  I downloaded USBDeview which lists the entire history of every device you connected via usb.

After viewing the entire history of every device ever connected via usb, I noticed several were from years back by looking at the last plug/unplug date.  I progressively starting selecting devices from 2 years ago and choosing uninstall selected device.  Repeat again for 1 years ago, etc.  I eventually did this for all devices except for those connected in the past month.

This solved my issue.  I can't explain why it did other than the history of old devices was gone so windows had nothing to probe or try to reconnect.  Its possible that as I disconnected or move devices around, something in windows was probing an old device and in the process, was disconnecting the device currently connected to that USB port.

Hope this works for others.

Answer (score -1):

For me it wasn't a USB device at all. Turns out it was my bluetooth adaptor. Just turned that off and everything was fine!

Comment: Okay, admittedly turning off the Bluetooth is not a "fix". But in my case I wasn't using Bluetooth at all so that was as far as I was willing to go to handle this issue. I think my answer has value in that the root of the issue could be non-USB related.