# How can I get a sound to play when I insert a specific USB drive in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, usb, events

So I get that Windows 8 has removed the ability to execute autorun instructions from a USB drive, so I was wondering if there was some alternative to that, where say, I could detect the drive and run something local to the computer.

I looked into setting up a task scheduler event, but I couldn't find any events that corresponded to inserting a USB drive (No new events were created in event viewer when I inserted one). Besides, that wouldn't differentiate between drives.

My end goal is to play a sound whenever the drive is inserted. Am I over thinking it?

What's my best shot at this? I'm open to coding something if that's ideal.

Comment: I did clarify in the comment that my goal with running the application was to play a sound. Applications are capable of playing sounds. The point is I want to trigger something, ANYTHING to happen when the USB drive is inserted.

Comment: Odd, many people are annoyed they [hear the sound too much](http://superuser.com/questions/505739/windows-8-constantly-plays-the-device-connect-sound)... So, you're saying you don't hear any sound when you plug in a USB device?

Comment: Can you open Control Panel -> Sound -> Sounds tab and tell me what is the Sound Scheme

Comment: Windows Default. The standard sound does play, but it does that for all connected USB devices. I specifically want a custom sound for one particular USB storage drive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two applications out there that might be able to do the trick. One is called USBDLM which is a Windows service running in the background and which is configured using a standard ini-file. And there is also APO USB Autorun which minimizes to a tray icon.

Check out the following link for further documentation:
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-make-windows-autorun-usb-flash-drives/